# How to grapple swing without face planting?

Tags: far-cry-4

I am trying to reach an unknown area on my map and it appears to be a long challenging path which involves using the grapple to swing between ledges.

It's the path which starts at the waypoint on my map and ends where the two question marks are.

[image: Far Cry Map]

The gaps in the path are ledges between which you have to swing using the grapple. You have to grapple and then swing and, I assume, detach when above the other ledge. However I keep killing myself by missing the ledge, detaching too late or landing too heavily.

What techniques can I employ to try and ensure my survival and prevent my death and having to run all the way back to the path and start over each time.

Comment: Did you try to rappel a bit more? I found easier when the rope is long enough. Also be quick to press the jump button in case Ajay can climb up the edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few techniques I use when swinging, but I agree it sometimes is a little annoying and easy to crater.

- Make a second pass whenever you need to curve around a cliff. Often the first swing will bring you out from the cliff wall. Swing back outwards so that your next swing forward will place you next to the ledge.
- Let out a little rope and take a running jump. This gives you momentum and more of a chance to grab the ledge instead of having to release and drop onto it.
- Release the rope just as you reach the ledge rather than waiting until the apex of your outward swing and dropping. Honestly, I have never died from landing on the ledge; either I make it or miss entirely, but the latter is pretty rare now (usually after a few beers).

Comment: Yeah, usually I release as the ledge is under me and sail gentle over the top of it and into a free fall faceplant. At least I have a wingsuit now, so that I can fly into the opposite cliff face first ;)

Comment: @DavidYell I swear, that damn wingsuit has killed me more times than the Royal Guard!